# Использование геттеров и сеттеров

Tags: java

Почему при компиляции выводит null?

```
public class Situating {
    String[] number = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
    String numbering;

   public void setnumbering(){
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        this.numbering=number[x];
    }
    String getNumbering(){
       return numbering;
   }
}

public class Launcher extends Situating {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Launcher launch=new Launcher();
        System.out.println(launch.getNumbering());
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что прежде чем что-то откуда-то взять, нужно его сначала туда положить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Launcher launch=new Launcher();
    launch.setNumbering();
    System.out.println(launch.getNumbering());
```